# Netty and BlockingQueue: How to synchronize peek and remove in a ChannelFutureListener?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, blockingqueue

I am using `BlockingQueue` to hold my messages and Netty for sending one by one. I am using peek() to check if message is available and then send it down the channel. When the operation is successful, I remove the message from the queue. However, I am not sure how to

1. make `peek()` and `remove()` synchronized? Since the removal takes place
   in another thread, I can't enclose the whole logic into the
   synchronized block. Can Semaphore do the job?
2. process one message at a time, i.e., `peek()` must not return another message until the first one is processed successfully.

This is I have tried so far:

```
public void run() {
    // Check if there is any message in the queue to send
    MyMessage message = queue.peek();
    if (message != null) {
      // There's a message to be sent so send this message now
      if (getChannelHandlerContext().channel().isActive()) {
        getLogger().debug("Sending data message");
        ChannelFuture cfuture = getChannelHandlerContext().writeAndFlush(message);
        cfuture.addListener((ChannelFutureListener) future -> {
          if (future.isSuccess()) {
            // Complete - we can safely remove the message from the queue
            getLogger().debug("Message has been sent successfully");
            boolean isRemoved = queue.remove(message);
            if (!isRemoved) {
              getLogger().warn("Message could not be removed from the queue.");
            }
          } else {
            getLogger().error("Could not send message successfully: " + future.cause().getMessage());
            future.channel().close();
          }
        });
      } else {
        getLogger().error("Attempting to send message before the channel is active");
      }
    } // else there's no message in the queue to send
  }
```

This thread is run every second using `ExecutionService`.

Does this sound correct? Or does it look overdone, i.e., I have read somewhere `writeAndFlush(message)` will always send the message, so it is safe to remove after this instead of moving the logic to `ChannelFutureListener`?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason why every message needs to be send 1 by one?

Comment: @Ferrybig, this is to send messages in order.